# How do i get the value of a query string

Tags: tags, querystring

I'm trying to get the value of a query string in the URL. I stumbled onto `{current_query_string}` which displays the whole query string. But i'm looking to get everything after the `=`.

```
{resource_tags backspace="5"}
   <a href="/segment_name_here?tag_id={tag_id}">{tag}</a>
{/resource_tags}
```

Basically i just want to get the `{tag_id}` part from the url so i can display a list of entries based on the `{tag_id}`.

So if the url is `/segment_name_here?tag_id=44` i just want the number `44`

Answer (score 1):

If your currently running on ExpressionEngine 6 you should be able to use the Request add-on (shipped as part of the core) to grab the GET variable.  Should be something along the following lines.

> {exp:request:get name="tag_id"}

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/request.html#request

Without seeing the template, there may also be a way to pass the tag id as a segment.